# General treatment of matrices with these properties

Tags: matrices, lie-groups

***edit: from my exchange with Travis, I am clarifying the question (edits are in bold).***

Suppose we define matrices $\alpha, \beta$ with these properties:

$$
\alpha=\alpha^\dagger\\
\beta=\beta^\dagger\\
\alpha^2=AI\\
\beta^2=BI\\
\alpha\beta+\beta\alpha=CI
$$

where $I$ is the identity, where $A,B,C$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}$. In the general case $A,B,C$ are independent of each other.

***Given prescribed values of A, B and C, my goal is to find the matrices $\alpha, \beta$.***

---

This can be extended to $n$ matrices, but I am only interested in case where $n\leq 4$. For example, the case with 3 matrices would be

$$
\alpha=\alpha^\dagger\\
\beta=\beta^\dagger\\
\gamma=\gamma^\dagger\\
\alpha^2=AI\\
\beta^2=BI\\
\gamma^2=CI\\
\alpha\beta+\beta\alpha=DI \\
\alpha\gamma+\gamma\alpha=EI\\
\beta\gamma+\gamma\beta=FI
$$

where $I$ is the identity, where $A,B,C,D,E,F$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}$. In the general case $A,B,C,D,E,F$ are independent of each other.

***My goal here again is to find the matrices $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ given some prescribed values of A,B,C,D,E,F.***

---

The case for four matrices would be.

$$
\alpha=\alpha^\dagger\\
\beta=\beta^\dagger\\
\gamma=\gamma^\dagger\\
\lambda=\lambda^\dagger\\
\alpha^2=AI\\
\beta^2=BI\\
\gamma^2=CI\\
\lambda^2=DI\\
\alpha\beta+\beta\alpha=EI \\
\alpha\gamma+\gamma\alpha=FI\\
\alpha\lambda+\lambda\alpha=GI\\
\beta\gamma+\gamma\beta=HI\\
\beta\lambda+\beta\lambda=JI\\
\gamma\lambda+\lambda\gamma=KI
$$

How would I go about characterizing the set of solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $\alpha = \alpha^\dagger$ is are exactly that the matrices are Hermitian, so $\alpha$ has real eigenvalues and is unitarily diagonalizable. Then, the conditions $\alpha^2 \in \Bbb R \cdot I$ imply that those eigenvalues are all $\pm q$ for some $q$ (in fact $A \geq 0$ and $q = \sqrt{A}$ but we don't need this fact). Thus, there is some unitary matrix $P$ such that
$$P \alpha P^{-1} = q \pmatrix{ I_{n - k} & \cdot \\\cdot&- I_{k}} .$$ Now, if we denote $\beta' := P \beta P^{-1}$, the condition $\alpha \beta + \beta \alpha = C I$ is equivalent to
$$\pmatrix{ I_{n - k} & \cdot \\\cdot&- I_k} \beta' + \beta' \pmatrix{ I_{n - k} & \cdot \\\cdot&- I_{k}} = rI$$
for some $r \in \Bbb R$. If we then denote $\beta' = \pmatrix{\lambda&T^\dagger\\T&\mu}$, then this condition is equivalent to $\lambda = s I$ and $\mu = -s I$ for some $F \in \Bbb R$.

In summary, the condition forces the existence of a $k \in \{0, \ldots, n\}$, a unitary matrix $P$, and a $k \times (n - k)$ matrix T such that such $$\alpha = q P^{-1} \pmatrix{ I_{n - k} & \cdot \\\cdot&- I_k} P, \qquad \beta = P^{-1} \pmatrix{s I_{n - k} & T^{\dagger}\\T & -s I_k} P .$$

So, in the case $n = 2$, the cases $k = 0, 2$ both imply that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are multiples of the identity. In the more interesting case $k = 1$, using the usual parameterization of $U(2)$ gives a parameterization of all of the remaining solutions $(\alpha, \beta)$.

Comment: What do the symbols $\cdot$ and $*$ means in the matrix. Also, would it be possible to give a specific example for n=2 where A, B and C are independent? For instance, I have found this example where A,B and C are independent, but $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not Hermitian, so it's coming short. $\alpha=\pmatrix{-C/(2\sqrt{B}) & A-C^2/(4B) \\ 1 & C/ (2 \sqrt{B})}$ and $\beta=\pmatrix{-\sqrt{B} & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{B}}$. Then $\alpha^2=A$, $\beta^2=B$ and $\alpha\beta+\beta\alpha=C$.

Comment: Here $\cdot$ is just a notation for $0$ (or zero blocks), to make the matrices easier to read, and $\ast$ just refers to blocks whose values are irrelevant for the current computation, but since we eventually name those blocks anyway, I've just replaced the $\ast$'s with $T, T^\dagger$. What do you mean by independent? Do you want to find $\alpha, \beta$ with prescribed $A, B, C$? (Note that one can't prescribe these entirely freely. Since $\alpha, \beta$ have real eigenvalues, $AI, BI$ have nonnegative eigenvalues and in particular $A, B$ are nonnegative.)

Comment: Yes! that is exactly what I mean - thanks for giving me the right terminology. Given some prescribed values of ,, my goal is to find  and  with the above-listed properties. To open up , to the negative values, I can relax the Hermitian requirement for  and  to instead be: either 1) hermitian or 2) anti-hermitian depending on the occasion. Do you think this is enough for solutions to exist?

Comment: No, in fact, substituting in the formulas in the answer gives (for $n = 2$) that $A = q^2, B = s^2, C = 2 q s$, so a necessary (and I think sufficient) condition is that $A, B \geq 0$ and $2 A B = C^2$, that is, $A, B$ determine $C$ up to sign. I'm not sure offhand about the effective of allowing anti-Hermitian matrices, too, but the analysis should be similar.

Comment: I think I might have found another solution and I would like to run it by you. Define $\alpha=\pmatrix{a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_4}$ and $\beta=\pmatrix{b_1 & b_2 \\ b_3 & b_4}$. My solution is $\alpha=\pmatrix{-a_1 & \overline{a_2} \\ a_2 & a_1}$ and $\beta=\pmatrix{-b_1 & \overline{b_2} \\ b_2 & b_1}$, where $a_1$ and $b_1$ are reals. Then, $A=a_1^2+a_2\overline{a_2}$, $B=b_1^2+b_2\overline{b_2}$ and $C=2a_1b_1+a_2\overline{b_2}+b_2\overline{a_2}$. We now have four variables $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$ to determine three constants $A,B,C$. Would $C$ then not be entirely determined by $A$ and $B$?